# Finding all values of $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\cosh(z)=-1$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> I am trying to solve $\cosh(z)=-1$.

So far, I have:
\begin{align}
\cosh(z)&=-1 \\
\frac{e^z+e^{-z}}{2}&=-1 \\
(e^z+1)^2&=0 \\
e^z&=-1 \ (\text{multiplicity 2}) \\
\implies z&=-\text{Log}(-1)+(2k+1)\pi i, \ \ k\in\mathbb{Z} \\
&=-(\ln|-1|+i\text{Arg}(-1))+(2k+1)\pi i \\
&=2k\pi i
\end{align}
But I know this is incorrect, as $\cosh((2k+1)\pi i)=-1$. Where have I gone so wrong?

Comment: $e^z=a$ means $z=Log a=\ln|-1|+i(2k+1)\pi$

Comment: It may help to recall $\cosh z=\cos iz$.

Comment: I could have used that identity, thanks @LordSharktheUnknown  In terms of my working out above, I am struggling at this point to identify the error.

Comment: @Nosrati should there not be a minus sign in front of Log?

Comment: Recall that $e^{x+iy}=e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)$.

Comment: @Bell No minus need and thanks to Lord's comment, this identity rescues from complex component.

Comment: If the minus sign isn't there, won't the answer be $2k\pi i+2\pi i$, which is still an even integer multiple of $i\pi$?

Comment: Perhaps I am confused when in the case when there is an odd integer multiple of $\pi i$. My textbook gives an example stating along the lines of $e^{iz}=-2\pm\sqrt{5}$ and we take the negative case, then $iz=\ln|-2-\sqrt{5}|+(2k+1)\pi i$." I am unsure why we do not use that logic here, as $-1$ is clearly negative.